# Only the first area map in a set of tabs shows up in IE 9 and down but works for every other browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 2 tabs with area maps on a couple pages but on every page in IE9 the map stops working on the second tab and only functions on the first. Any ideas why? I'm using jquery tabs.

The code is below:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>Retail Collection-Upper Concourse</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Dining Collection- The Eatery</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="fragment-1">
<img src="images/royal-bank-plaza3.png" width="620" height="404" class="map" usemap="#map1">
<map name="map1" style="padding:0">
<area id="property1" shape="poly" coords="108.313,276.238,82.562,250.486,117.567,215.659,117.567,212.466,152.584,212.466,152.584,250.177,143.405,241.149" class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://www.oxfordurbanretail.com/royal-bank-plaza/bb-buggy/?id=lightbox" class="group" >
</map>
   <span class="col3">
    <ul class="stores">
      <a class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://www.oxfordurbanretail.com/royal-bank-plaza/bb-buggy/?id=lightbox"><li id="location1">BB Buggy</li></a>
        <a class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://www.oxfordurbanretail.com/royal-bank-plaza/brooks-brothers-canada/?id=lightbox"><li id="location2">Brooks Brothers Canada</li></a>
    </ul>
         </span>
    </div>
  <div id="fragment-2">
       <img src="images/royal-bank-plaza3.png" width="620" height="404" class="map" usemap="#map2">
      <map name="map2" style="padding:0">
    <area id="property1" shape="poly" coords="108.313,276.238,82.562,250.486,117.567,215.659,117.567,212.466,152.584,212.466,152.584,250.177,143.405,241.149" class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://www.oxfordurbanretail.com/royal-bank-plaza/bb-buggy/?id=lightbox" class="group" >
</map>
   <span class="col3">
    <ul class="stores">
      <a class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://www.oxfordurbanretail.com/royal-bank-plaza/bb-buggy/?id=lightbox"><li id="location1">BB Buggy</li></a>
        <a class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://www.oxfordurbanretail.com/royal-bank-plaza/brooks-brothers-canada/?id=lightbox"><li id="location2">Brooks Brothers Canada</li></a>
    </ul>
         </span>
    </div>
```